# When does the projection matrix become the identity? How to show it mathematically?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to show mathematically that if I project a vector b onto a space that is spanned by a matrix A, which is invertible, the projection matrix P is the identity matrix.
I can explain it geometrically that in that case b is element of the space, hence, the projection of b is b, but how do I show this in a concise mathematical fashion?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: $P^2=P$, so $P^{-1}P^2=P^{-1}P$, so...

Comment: @Ian: thanks for your comment. This really helped. I expanded on it in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When A is invertible, the following holds:

$P=A*(A^{T}*A)^{-1}*A^{T}=A*(A^{-1}*(A^{T})^{-1})*A^{T}=I$

because:
$(A^{T}*A)*(A^{T}*A)^{-1}=A^{T}*A*A^{-1}*(A^{T})^{-1}=I$